# Join table and find there min/max(Collection)

Tags: mysql, select, join, hql

I have a structure:

```
public class ChosenCourseDate {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="chosencoursedate_id")
    List<ChosenCourseDatePeriod> chosenCourseDatePeriod;
}

public class ChosenCourseDatePeriod {

    Date startDateTime;
    Date endDateTime;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="chosencoursedate_id")
    ChosenCourseDate chosenCourseDate;
}
```

I want to add a new condition into an existed select statement to find objects by earliest startDateTime in ChosenCourseDatePeriod.

1)Select statement:

```
select registration from CourseRegistration registration
left join registration.chosenCourseDate as chosencoursedate
left join chosencoursedate.chosenCourseDatePeriod as period
where registration.candidate =:candidate
and registration.course =:course
and min(period.startDateTime) >=:now;
```

Result:

> Invalid use of group function

2)Select statement:

```
select registration, min(period.startDateTime) as earliestDate from CourseRegistration registration
left join registration.chosenCourseDate as chosencoursedate
left join chosencoursedate.chosenCourseDatePeriod as period
where registration.candidate =:candidate
and registration.course =:course
and earliestDate >=:now;
```

Result:

> Unknown column 'earliestDate' in 'where clause', cause: null

3) I decided to use 2 `SELECT` statements, it helped.

```
select registration from CourseRegistration registration
    left join registration.chosenCourseDate as chosencoursedate
    where registration.candidate =:candidate
    and registration.course =:course
    and (SELECT min(period.startDateTime) FROM ChosenCourseDate inChosenCourseDate join inChosenCourseDate.chosenCourseDatePeriod period where inChosenCourseDate = chosenCourseDate) >=:now;
```

What's wrong with my first and second solutions? Does it possible to do only one `SELECT` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use aggregation functions on the `WHERE` clause, or without a `GROUP BY` clause. If you want to check against the maximum date, add a `GROUP BY` clause and use the `HAVING` for conditions on aggregation functions :

```
SELECT registration
FROM CourseRegistration registration
LEFT JOIN registration.chosenCourseDate chosencoursedate
LEFT JOIN chosencoursedate.chosenCourseDatePeriod period
WHERE registration.candidate =:candidate
  AND registration.course =:course
GROUP BY registration
HAVING min(period.startDateTime) >=:now;
```

Your second query is invalid too, it should only work for old versions of MySQL , since you're lacking a `GROUP BY` clause. The other reason is - you can't use a derived column (column made by you) in the same layer it is being created, so the solution is to wrap it with another select:

```
SELECT * FROM ( Your query... ) // It is not available inside the query
WHERE earliestDate>=:now; // It is now available
```